# WinError 10004 with PySide and Socket in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am working on Python project (as I usually mentioned in my question). My friend coding in internet connection part and she got a problem.

My friend coding both server&client side and our program also has a GUI. Then, my friend create a new thread to seperate between listening for connection and GUI process.

Our socket code is shown below

```
def start(self):
        self.t = Thread( target = self.startServer )
        self.t.start()
def stop(self):
       self.socket.close()
       self.t._stop()
def startServer(self):
    try:
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind( (self.host, self.port ) )
        print("\nBound to port: " + str(self.port) )
        self.socket.listen(5)
    except socket.error:
        print("\nSocket connection error")
        sys.exit(1)

    while True:
        print("\nListening at " + str(self.socket.getsockname()))
        sc, sockname = self.socket.accept()
```

The problem is when self.socket.close() is called, we get this error

[image: WinError 10004]

Is there a solution to solve this?

Ps.My friend does not sure that is this is a correct way to create a new thread. The reason is when press start and stop button (it is the same button), it show the message that it iw listening many times.

The problem is shown below (my friend click start-stop-start).

[image]

Thank you for answer(s) and suggestion(s).

Comment: IHMO multithreading (*at least Python threads*) is not the best approach here. You should consider using an Asynchronous frameowork such as Twisted, Asyncio, Gevent or circuits and integrate that into your GUI's main event loop.

Comment: YOu will have better results in a Concurrency and I/O framework that specializes in doing this kind of thing. It's mostly about I/O and event handling.